# How would I implement "lazy execution timer" using RXJS

Tags: angular, rxjs, settimeout

I had a use case where due to template issues Angular's error handler got bombarded with 25+ error messages. Since my custom error handler is using remote logger (sentry.io) the app became unresponsive with too many API requests to sentry.io.

For now I resolved the issue using "lazy timer" approach like so:

```
import { ErrorHandler, Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { LoggingService } from './sentry.provider';

@Injectable()
export class GlobalErrorHandler implements ErrorHandler {

    private errorBuffer: Array<any>;
    private lazyTimer: any;

    constructor(private logger: LoggingService) {

        this.errorBuffer = [];

    };

    handleError(error) {

        this.errorBuffer.push(error);
        this.processErrorBuffer();

    };

    private processErrorBuffer() {

        if (this.lazyTimer) { clearTimeout(this.lazyTimer) };

        this.lazyTimer = setTimeout(() => {

            if (this.errorBuffer.length === 1) {

                let error = this.errorBuffer.pop();
                this.logger.reportError(error);

            } else if (this.errorBuffer.length > 1) {

                this.logger.reportError(this.errorBuffer);
                this.errorBuffer = [];

            };

        }, 300)
        
    };

}
```

So basically after each error instead of handling it I setTimeout which will execute error handling logic or will get cleared and renewed (if new error comes in within 300ms).

This way I can send either a single error to Sentry or a batch (array).

I tried to implement the same logic using RXJS but failed to find a way to do so.
I seem to fail to understand which operator performs such renewal of timer.

**So which operator I would need to use to replicate this behavior using RXJS?**

Comment: are you familar with the `debounceTime` operator? you can do the same with this.

Comment: yeah I looked into debounceTime, but that just gives the last emitted value? I still need to capture all errors not just last one. At least can't see how I can use debounce for this case with bursts of emitted values. Or you mean storing all errors in an array and only emit entire array?

Comment: Ah! you can use debouceTime and ReplaySubject. does it make sense?

Comment: ReplaySubject takes the number of the last edited values. let me research maybe I can find something for get all of the emitted values instead of last ones.

Comment: yeah ideally all emitted since last debounce "event" would be perfect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**DebounceTime description(source from RXJS documentation):**

https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/debounceTime

> Emits a value from the source Observable only after a particular time
> span has passed without another source emission.

How I could see, you are removing all of the errors after calling `this.logger.reportError` function, so no need to use ReplaySubject.

Depends on your function logic I did it in this way. Please check the example.

```
import { ErrorHandler, Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { LoggingService } from './sentry.provider';
import { debounceTime, scan } from 'rxjs/operators'

@Injectable()
export class GlobalErrorHandler implements ErrorHandler {

    private errorListener = new Subject();   // <-- you need to import subject from RXJS

    constructor(private logger: LoggingService) {
        this.errorListener
           .pipe(
              // scan operator will collect all of the responses in one array 
              scan((acc, curr) => [...acc, curr], []), 
              // debounceTime operator will trigger event for the listeners only once when after the last action passed 400 ms 
              debounceTime(400)
            ).subscribe(errorBuffer => { 
                // errorBuffer is the collected errors list
                this.processErrorBuffer(errorBuffer);
            })
    };

    handleError(error) {
        this.errorListener.next(error);
    };

    private processErrorBuffer(errorBuffer) {
      if (errorBuffer.length === 1) {

          this.logger.reportError(errorBuffer[0]);
       } else if (this.errorBuffer.length > 1) {

           this.logger.reportError(errorBuffer);
       };
    };

}
```

Comment: let me test it tomorrow thoroughly. I think this works so timer kicks in every 300ms in this case regardless of volume of errors coming in and since we put them all into an array we do not technically loosing errors. Let me test this and confirm. I wonder if there is combination of operators that can do the same without array. I looked into bufferCount but still not sure how woudl I implement it.

Comment: @SergeyRudenko Yes, let me know after your test, I will try to find a way do the same with the ReplaySubject. It will be great if we can figure out with that. I haven't used ReplaySubject so the solution is interesting for me too.

Comment: Perfect, just tested and it works great! thank you so much. Learned something today:)